# jQuery toggle() with parameter doesn't work

Tags: jquery, toggle

I need some help with an issue that is driving me crazy.

I have the following code:

```
$(".portlet-collapse").live({
    mousedown: function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    },
    click: function () {
        if ($(this).css("background-position") != "-96px -288px") {
            $(this).css("background-position", "-96px -288px");
        }
        else {
            $(this).css("background-position", "-144px -288px");
        }

        $(this).parent().parent().children('.portlet-content:first').toggle();
    }
});
```

This works fine.

When I now put a parameter in the toggle function, it doesn't toggle anymore.
I have tried the following:

```
$(this).parent().parent().children('.portlet-content:first').toggle("fast");
$(this).parent().parent().children('.portlet-content:first').toggle("slow");
$(this).parent().parent().children('.portlet-content:first').toggle(3000);
$(this).parent().parent().children('.portlet-content:first').toggle("fast", function () { alert("toggle me"); });
```

Every of this options brakes the toggle. After 2 hours searching I have even tried:

Then I have tried to switch over to slideToggle(). But even that don't works.

The real funny thing is, I use the same functionality with the same principle for different elements in my application and it works everywhere without a problem.

I just can't follow the logic, why it works empty, but stops working with parameter.

Perhaps someone can enlighten me.

Thank you in advance

Edit:

Ok, the problem must be somehow related to the element I want to toggle. I have for testing exchanged the selected element in the code above and I have no problems.

Here is the script I use to load a portlet:

```
function CreateWidget(columnid,tagid, title) {
$("<div class='portlet' id='" + tagid + "_portlet'>
    <div class='portlet-header' style='cursor:move;'>
        <span class='portlet-title'>" + title + "</span>
        <span class='portlet-remove' style='cursor:pointer;'></span>
        <span class='portlet-collapse' style='cursor:pointer;'></span>
        <span class='portlet-fullscreen' style='cursor:pointer;'></span>
    </div>
    <div class='portlet-content' id='" + tagid + "_content'>
    </div>
    </div>")
.appendTo("#" + columnid);
};
```

The content of the div with the class "portlet-content" is loaded later via $.ajax()

Does anyone perhaps see something I overlook all the time?

Comment: Your code works here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/B3xeH/1/ - so your problem isn't in the code you're showing.

Comment: Exactly that is my comprehension problem in the moment. I know that the code is working and before posting the question here I have tried it several times in test applications. I just can't figure out, what kind of error I have somewhere, that let $("#").toggle(); work, but not $("#").toggle("fast");

Comment: What happens when you try specifying the milliseconds for the transition, i.e. 400 instead of 'fast'?

Comment: Makes no difference. I can put in whatever I want it will not work. The duration is not really a matter for me, but I need the callback function

Comment: Ok, I have found the problem myself.

It seems to be that .live() and .toggle() / .slideToggle() are not really compatible and the combination gives only problems.

I have now exchanged my toggle with manual created behaviour and I have no problem anymore.

But thank anyway for the good comments.

Comment: Add that as a solution (so other people who search and see your problem can see the solution).  And maybe file a bug report with jQuery / jQuery UI?